# use regex for parsing mail in mbox

Tags: java, regex, email, mbox

I want to get the following information based on regex and java technologies, where the start tag is "FROM mail@mail.com Time" and the end tag is "FROM mail@mail.com Time" or end of String. The result shall only contain the start tag and the content between the start and end tag but not the end tag. Background is I want to get the emails in the mbox format with regular expressions. Begin is marked with "FROM mail@mail.com Time" and the end of the mail is either the beginning of the next mail or end of file.

So I have the following schema:

```
FROM mail@mail.com Time  
Text1  

FROM mail@mail.com Time  

Text2  

FROM mail@mail.com Time  
Text3
```

My code:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(Start_Tag+"(.*?)"+End_Tag,Pattern.DOTALL);  
Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(mbox_content);  
while (matcher.find())  
{  
System.out.println(matcher.group());  
}
```

I used this, but it does not work. Can anybody support me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do Start_Tag and End_Tag themselves represent a regex?

Answer (score 0):

```
String MailAdress_complete_Tag="([a-zA-Z][\\w\\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z][\\w\\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\\.][a-zA-Z])";
String MailAdress_without_country="([a-zA-Z][\\w\\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z][\\w\\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])";

String MailAdress_Tag="("+MailAdress_complete_Tag+"|"+MailAdress_without_country+"|MAILER-DAEMON)";
String Time_Tag="[a-zA-Z0-9: ]{24}";
String Start_Tag="From\\s"+MailAdress_Tag+"*\\s\\s"+Time_Tag;
String End_Tag=LineSeparator+LineSeparator+"((?="+Start_Tag+")|$)"; 
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(Start_Tag+"(.*?)"+End_Tag,Pattern.DOTALL);
```

This script extracts mails out of mbox file. It works for my purpose.